# How to set proxy configuration file in command line?

Tags: macos, network, proxy

Sometimes I need to use [ShadowsocksX](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-iOS/tree/master/ShadowsocksX) to bypass [GFW](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E9%98%B2%E7%81%AB%E9%95%BF%E5%9F%8E), but ShadowsocksX will clear my proxy configuration file.

When I come to my company, I've to set proxy configuration file manually, I'm wondering if there any OSX's command can help me to set  proxy configuration file? So that I can create an alias in my zshrc file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`networksetup` is a configuration tool for network settings in System Preferences. I don't really known what the ShadowsocksX project is,
but this command can help you up.

For instance, for a certain `.pac` config file, you could do:

```
networksetup -setautoproxyurl "Wi-Fi" "http://somedomain.com/proxy.pac"
```

PS: if you just need to set the proxy for something like wget, or curl, then you can use the fairly universal `http_proxy` and `ftp_proxy` ENV variables (e.g., `export http_proxy=http://myproxy:port`).

Comment: Thanks, it's `networksetup -setautoproxyurl "Wi-Fi" "http://somedomain.com/proxy.pac"`

Comment: @tli2020 Thanks buddy, not sure why this comment is not the answer...

Comment: @SRG Thanks for updating the answer:)

Comment: @tli2020 My pleasure, thanks to you for providing the answer!

Comment: ping github.com in terminal still doesn't get proxy-ed ... any way to fix this?